# Cannot import openpyxl properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Hey so I'm quite new to programming. When I try to import openpyxl module to Python I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "X:\*filepath*\*filename*.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openpyxl

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .workbook import *

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 15, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .worksheet import *

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 43, in <module>
    from openpyxl.formatting import ConditionalFormatting

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .rules import CellIsRule, ColorScaleRule, FormatRule, FormulaRule

  File "C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\rules.py", line 5, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping

ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\*User Name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I have installed openpyxl using the terminal. I read other threads but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in your code:

```
openpyxl import workbook
```

Instead that use:

```
openpyxl import Workbook
```